# Responsive issue on mobile menu

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, menu, navigation

I've implemented the mobile menu from here:

http://johnm.io/project/hamburgler/

to

http://helloarchie.blue

But for some reason the menu items are gone and the menu doesn't show up over the top of my content. I've pasted the code exactly as is and it's not surrounded by any other HTML.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `z-index: 1` to `.hamburgler-menu` and to `#hamburgler`, and changing `position: absolute` for `position: fixed` to `.hamburgler-menu` will fix it.

Anyways, for what I can see there, you are trying to make one menu for desktop and a different (replicated) one for mobile. That's a bad practice for SEO purposes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ah, thankyou! I knew it would be something simple. Perfect!